# How to add images to custom listview using Simple Adapter in android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I'm making a movies app using JSON requests, etc. So I have a listview that shows movies data such as actors, directors, parental guide, IMDB etc. Here is the code for putting these data in listview:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                movies.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_new, new String[]{"name", "actors",
                "story", "imrating", "genre","guide", "director"}, new int[]{R.id.title,
                R.id.actors_txt, R.id.story,  R.id.rating, R.id.genre,R.id.parental, R.id.director_txt, R.id.year, R.id.imageView8, R.id.imageView10, R.id.backgroundimg});

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

.. and here is the problem that I have IMDB icon, so it comes like that `<imdbicon>` 6.2(from JSON) but the image itself from the app in imageview in the layout file for the listview.

```
R.id.imageView8, R.id.imageView10, R.id.backgroundimg
```

these three I want in the listview but I can't figure how

Answer (score 0):

You can make a subclass of `SimpleAdapter` and override `setImageView` to get an image based on your text:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                movies.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_new, new String[]{"name", "actors",
                "story", "imrating", "genre","guide", "director"}, new int[]{R.id.title,
                R.id.actors_txt, R.id.story,  R.id.rating, R.id.genre,R.id.parental, R.id.director_txt, R.id.year, R.id.imageView8, R.id.imageView10, R.id.backgroundimg}) {

    @Override
    public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) {

         // here you put code to take your "value" string
         // and get your image, for example using Picasso
         // or Glide, and putting it in the "v" ImageView.
    }
 };
```

Comment: Considering use of `R.id.imageView8, R.id.imageView10, R.id.backgroundimg`, I think `setViewImage` with the int param would be more correct

Comment: Fantastic! I'd be grateful if you could accept my answer as correct.